chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127 using Airflow-Docker
I have tried several solutions but it's still showing this error:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/airflow/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/124.0.6367.155/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
My Dockerfile:
FROM apache/airflow:latest

# Copy your DAGs into the container
COPY dags/ /opt/airflow/dags/

FROM openjdk:17-slim

# please review all the latest versions here:
# https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=120.0.6099.7

### install chrome
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get install -y zip
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

### install chromedriver
RUN wget https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip \
  && unzip chromedriver-linux64.zip && rm -dfr chromedriver_linux64.zip \
  && mv /chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver /home/airflow/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/124.0.6367.155/ \
  && chmod +x /home/airflow/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/124.0.6367.155/

###
 # REST OF YOUR DOKCERFILE HERE
###


installing the google-chrome and webdriver using Dockerfile
installing through ubuntu

